# Correlation Names, how to use them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

### Problem

I am trying to add a second join to a query however when i add the secone line

```
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets ON Assets.AssetTypeID = AssetTypes.AssetTypeID
```

SQL Server throws this error

```
Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The objects "dbo.Assets" and "dbo.Assets" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.
```

### Query

```
SELECT DENumber, AcquiredDate, ItemDescription, ItemName, LocationName, AssetTypeID
FROM dbo.Assets 
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations ON Assets.LocationId = Locations.LocationId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets ON Assets.AssetTypeID = AssetTypes.AssetTypeID     
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 7
```

### Question

How do I edit the query to allow both JOINS to work? Possibly using correlation names?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: sorry i'll edit the question

Comment: So you do not know how to declare and use a correlation name?

Comment: @DanCundy, post the `CREATE TABLE` scripts of your 'Assets' table and your 'AssetTypes' table.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are linking to `Assets` twice, and you meant to link to `AssetTypes` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets ON Assets.AssetTypeID = AssetTypes.AssetTypeID
```

here is some issue, assettypes is also a table? then why you are not join in your query.

Always give alias name and try to make sort to understand as

```
SELECT Distinct --to remove un-wanted duplicate rows
--I don't know, so you will add alias before each column to avoid error.
DENumber, A.AcquiredDate, ItemDescription, ItemName, LocationName, AssetTypeID 

FROM dbo.Assets A
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations L ON A.LocationId = L.LocationId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets A1 ON A.AssetTypeID = A1.AssetTypeID
--INNER JOIN dbo.AssetsTypes AT ON A.AssetTypeID = AT.AssetTypeID      --if assettypes you want to join
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, A.AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 7
```

Comment: Yes assettypes is also a table.

Comment: ok, so you just uncomment the inner join line and check again. Check my comments start with --

Comment: Ambiguous column name on all select columns that don't have an alias. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'DENumber'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'ItemDescription'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'ItemName'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'AssetTypeID'.

Comment: dear give alias name before each column. please see my comment in updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT a1.DENumber, a1.AcquiredDate, a1.ItemDescription, a1.ItemName, a1.LocationName, a1.AssetTypeID
FROM dbo.Assets a1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations ON a1.LocationId = Locations.LocationId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets a2 ON a2.AssetTypeID = a1.AssetTypeID     
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, a1.AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 7
```

Comment: Get Ambiguous column name error?

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'DENumber'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'AcquiredDate'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'ItemDescription'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'ItemName'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Comment: @DanCundy Missed that, updated it.

Comment: This statement produces duplicate rows for some reason?

Comment: One of your joins must be matching on more than one row, i.e. there's "1" in your `a1.LocationId` and there are more than 1 record with "LocationId" of 1 in "Locations" table. Or the 2nd join.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you reference a table at least twice in the `FROM` clause and you did not specify a table alias to either table so that SQL Server can distinguish one from the other.

In your query you added `Assets` table in the `FROM` clause without any Alias name also `Assets` table in the `Inner Join` without any Alias, try to improve your query like,

```
SELECT DENumber, AcquiredDate, ItemDescription, ItemName, LocationName, AssetTypeID
FROM dbo.Assets ATS
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations LOC ON ATS.LocationId = LOC.LocationId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Assets ATS1 ON ATS.AssetTypeID = ATS1.AssetTypeID     
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) >= 7
```

for more info on the error you are getting refer http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1013.aspx